# make address line 2 inout element optional

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `html form` and I'm using `Jquery` to validate input elements but the issue is that the script is validating all input text fields and not validating select fields. Also I need to make the address line 2 input text field set to optional and the select fields must be required.

```
<fieldset>
<div class="form-bottom">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="addres 1" id="add1" name="" value="" |>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="address 2" id="add2" name="" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="city" id="city" name="" value="" |>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Home Phone" id="contact_number" name="" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
 < script >
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.registration-form fieldset:first-child').fadeIn('slow');

    $('.registration-form input[type="text"]').on('focus', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('input-error');
    });

    // next step
    $('.registration-form .btn-next').on('click', function() {
        var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
        var next_step = true;

        parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
                next_step = false;
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
        });

        if (next_step) {
            parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function() {
                $(this).next().fadeIn();
            });
        }

    });

    // previous step
    $('.registration-form .btn-previous').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parents('fieldset').fadeOut(400, function() {
            $(this).prev().fadeIn();
        });
    });

    // submit
    $('.registration-form').on('submit', function(e) {

        $(this).find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
        });

    });

}); < /script>
```

Comment: Show us the validation script you have in place..

Comment: I posted the script

Comment: You posted only form elements. Where is the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to validate address2. You can just ignore it. Try this.

Jquery

```
 $('.registration-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        $(this).find('input:text[name!=add2],input[type="email"]').each(function() { // this will filter input of having name of add2
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
        });

    });
```

HTML

```
   <form class="registration-form" name="register">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-bottom">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="addres 1" id="add1" name="" value="" |>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="address 2" id="add2" name="add2" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="city" id="city" name="" value="" |>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Home Phone" id="contact_number" name=""
                           value="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work, also I have dropdown select fields which I need to make required.

Comment: I am not sure what are you talking about but when you submit form add2 is not validate. Tried with the above code.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it still keeps the field required, if you see the script on the top part of script we are adding the class input-error for validation, I don't know if we need to make some changes there since it is a step form the form will not move to next step unless it passes validation. Also I have a select dropdown element and I need to make that required, any suggestion on that will be helpful.

Comment: It worked I was misisng the ! symbol, how do i make the <select> element required in the same form.